# Не могу передать переменую из одной функции в другую

Tags: javascript, функции, переменные

Код:

```
function one() {
    var target = 5;
    return target;
}

function second() {
    var target = one();
    console.log(target);
}
```

Помогите, не передаеться переменная из функции `one()` в `second()`

Comment: Все работает. Вы не забыли случайно вызвать функцию `second()`?

Comment: @Simon да, я вызываю функцию, но при вызове функции `second()` мне выдает ошибку Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: А где Вы ее вызываете? Если на SO добавить пример кода, то все работает. Обычно к такой ошибке приводит рекурсия, которая порождает цепочку последовательных вызовов, что соответственно ведет к наполнению стека вызовов.

Comment: Показывайте настоящий код.

Comment: @Simon я её вызывал после `var target = 5;`

Comment: "я её вызывал после var target = 5; " --- А зачем?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский код и так, и так не работает

Comment: @Brin  вы врёте...

Comment: @АлексейШиманский боже зачем мне врать? Специально что бы програма не работала?

Comment: @Brin конечно вы не врёте, просто магия вселенной заставляет у вас текущий код не работать, а у других - функционировать исправно)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function one() {
    var target = 5;
    return target;
}

function second() {
    var target = one();
    console.log(target);
}


second();
```